# I'm stuck building a line reader with interfaces in Java

Tags: java, interface

I'm trying to make it so my program

- chooses a file
- reads the code one line at a time
- uses an interface to do three different things

  - convert to uppercase
  - count the number of characters
  - save to a file ("copy.txt")

I'm stuck with the formatting parts. For instance, I'm not sure where the `println` commands needs to be. Any help will definitely be appreciated. I'm a beginner and still learning basic things.

**Interface for Processing Individual Strings:**

```
public interface StringProcessor
{
void process(String s);
}
```

**Processing Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
class FileProcessor
{
private Scanner infile;
public FileProcessor(File f) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = infile.nextLine();
}
public String go(StringProcessor a)
{
    a.process(line);
}
}
```

**Driver Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Driver
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    File inputFile = null;
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        inputFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
    FileProcessor infile = new FileProcessor(inputFile);
    int total=0;
}
}
```

**This Would Make Each Line Uppercase:**

```
public class Upper implements StringProcessor
{
public void process(String s)
{
    while (infile.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println(infile.nextLine().toUpperCase());
    }
}
}
```

**This Would Count Characters:**

```
public class Count implements StringProcessor
{
public void process(String s)
{
    while (infile.hasNextLine())
    {
        int charactercounter = infile.nextLine().length();
        total = total+charactercounter;
    }
}
}
```

**This Would Print to a File:**

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Print implements StringProcessor
{
public void process(String s)
{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("copy.txt");
    while (infile.hasNextLine())
    {
        out.println(infile.nextLine());
    }
    out.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Finding solutions to all of these problems individually can be done with a simple Google search. We aren't here to solve your homework for you wholesale.

Comment: It's not multiple homework programs. It's one big assignment. I'm just asking to see if I'm making any obvious mistakes or if something needs to be moved somewhere else.

Comment: It not being multiple problems does not change anything. And this isn't a code review site either (there is a specific site in the SO network for code-reviews)

Comment: I don't completely understand where you're stuck, but you seem to have a misunderstanding on how interfaces work. If you implement an interface you need to implement all its methods, so you wouldn't build a different implementations of your StringProcessor interface for each of its method.

Comment: It's obvious you don't grok the concept of interfaces. Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: @aruidante I'm sorry. Where is this specific site?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Not sure why it's not one of the options for an off-topic flag. Sorry if I came off harsh, there's just a lot of 'solve my homework for me' type questions on here lately and they get tiresome.

Comment: @aruisdante I wasn't wanting the solution. Just wanted to know what I should do next or if I screwed anything up.

Comment: @user3067497 could you expand upon the requirements a little clearer?

Comment: @aruisdante 1) there's no direct migration route for any beta sites. 2) please read Code Review's [on-topic page](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before [raising a custom moderator flag to get a SO question migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207046/197901) (that's how one gets a question migrated to CR). 3) CR doesn't need "solve my homework for me" type questions either.

Comment: @aruisdante: Despite us being a beta site (no migration paths), we don't take "solve my homework" questions, either.  We only take *working code*, where the OP just wants the working solution improved in any way.

Comment: @JamesKhoury The exact quote was: "For this last program, we are going to build a class that reads one line at a time from a file and uses a
callback (interface) to process each line.". Also, I figured out a few things, so refresh the page because is going to be very different.

Comment: @aruisdante Because it is in Beta. I still wish it were available though I find a lot of questions that belong there.

Comment: Suggestion to original poster: Simplify your question. Ask ONE SPECIFIC QUESTION about ONE SPECIFIC POINT that you're struggling with. That will tremendously increase your odds of actually getting a useful answer. We aren't going to read, analyze, and rewrite your entire program for you; that's simply not what Stack Overflow is for. We *will* help you understand how to perform a very specific programming task, if it's clear that you've made an effort but are still struggling with it. Part of "making an effort" includes attempting to debug it yourself first.

Comment: @JamesKhoury Thank you for editing my question to make it easier to read. Do you have any advice on how to correct the code?

Answer (score 2):

Java was one of the first programming languages I learned and once you get it, it's so beautiful. Here is the solution for you homework, but now you have a new homework assignment. Go and figure out what is doing what and label it with notes. So next time you have a similar problem you can go over your old codes and cherry pick what you need. We were all noobs at some point so don't take it to bad.

**StringProcessor.java**

```
public interface StringProcessor {

     public String Upper(String str);
     public int Count(String str);
     public void Save(String str, String filename);

}
```

**FileProcessor.java**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class FileProcessor implements StringProcessor{

public FileProcessor(){

}

// Here we get passed a string and make it UpperCase
@Override
public String Upper(String str) {

    return str.toUpperCase();
}

// Here we get passed a string and return the length of it
@Override
public int Count(String str) {

    return str.length();
}

// Here we get a string and a file name to save it as
@Override
public void Save(String str, String filename) {
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);

        fw.write(str);
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Error: " +e.toString());
    }finally{
        System.out.println ("Output file has been created: " + filename);
    }

}

}
```

**Driver.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Driver {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Welcome to the File Processor");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\nWould you like to begin? (yes or no): ");

    String startProgram = scan.next();

    if(startProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){

        System.out.println("\nSelect a file.\n");

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        File inputFile = null;

        if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

            inputFile = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            try{
            Scanner file = new Scanner(inputFile);
            file.useDelimiter("\n");
            String data = "";
            FileProcessor fp = new FileProcessor();

            while (file.hasNext()){

                String line = file.next();
                System.out.println("Original: " +line);
                System.out.println("To Upper Case: " +fp.Upper(line));
                System.out.println("Count: " +fp.Count(line));
                System.out.println();
                data += line;
            }


            System.out.println("\nFile Processing complete!\n");
            System.out.print("Save copy of file? (yes or no): ");

            String save = scan.next();

            if(save.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){

                fp.Save(data, "copy.txt");
                System.out.println("\nProgram Ending... Goodbye!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("\nProgram Ending... Goodbye!");
            }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }else{

        System.out.println("\nProgram Ending... Goodbye!");
    }

}
}
```

**text.txt**

```
some text here to test the file
and to see if it work correctly
```

Just a note when you save the file "copy.txt", it will show up in your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

As your problem operates on streams of characters, there is already a good Java interface to implement.  Actually, they are two abstract classes: [`FilterReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FilterReader.html) or [`FilterWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FilterWriter.html) — extending either one will work.  Here, I've chosen to extend `FilterWriter`.

For example, here is an example of a `Writer` that keeps track of how many characters it has been asked to write:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CharacterCountingWriter extends FilterWriter {
    private long charCount = 0;

    public CharacterCountingWriter(Writer out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public void write(int c) throws IOException {
        this.charCount++;
        out.write(c);
    }

    public void write(char[] buf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        this.charCount += len;
        out.write(buf, off, len);
    }

    public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        this.charCount += len;
        out.write(str, off, len);
    }

    public void resetCharCount() {
        this.charCount = 0;
    }

    public long getCharCount() {
        return this.charCount;
    }

}
```

Based on that model, you should be able to implement a `UpperCaseFilterWriter` as well.

Using those classes, here is a program that copies a file, uppercasing the text and printing the number of characters in each line as it goes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

    try (CharacterCountingWriter ccw = new CharacterCountingWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
         UpperCaseFilterWriter ucfw = new UpperCaseFilterWriter(ccw);
         Writer pipeline = ucfw) {  // pipeline is just a convenient alias

        String line;
        while (null != (line = in.readLine())) {
            // Print count of characters in each line, excluding the line
            // terminator
            ccw.resetCharCount();
            pipeline.write(line);
            System.out.println(ccw.getCharCount());
            pipeline.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        pipeline.flush();
    }
}
```